# Improve the performance of recursion for generating tree using JSON data

Tags: javascript, performance, recursion

I need to construct a tree structure from data represented in JSON as object and parent relationship. I have implemented below code which is successfully doing the job but I am not sure whether it's giving the best performance (I mean doing the job in as less as possible iteration).

Please Note, the root of the tree is represented as `parent` is same as `object`. e.g. `{"object":"A", "parent":"A"}`

Suggestions about any other implementation with better performance would be helpful!!

```js
var jsonInput =
[
{"object":"A", "parent":"A"},
{"object":"B", "parent":"A"},
{"object":"C", "parent":"A"},
{"object":"D", "parent":"B"},
{"object":"E", "parent":"B"},
{"object":"F", "parent":"D"},
{"object":"G", "parent":"D"},
{"object":"H", "parent":"E"},
{"object":"I", "parent":"E"},
{"object":"J", "parent":"C"},
{"object":"K", "parent":"C"},
{"object":"L", "parent":"J"},
{"object":"M", "parent":"J"},
{"object":"N", "parent":"K"},
{"object":"O", "parent":"K"},
{"object":"P", "parent":"N"},
{"object":"Q", "parent":"N"},
{"object":"R", "parent":"O"},
{"object":"S", "parent":"O"}
];

var root = getRoot();
root.childs = findChildrens(root);

console.log("The tree hierarchy is:")
console.log(root);

function getRoot() {
var root;
for (var counter = 0; counter < jsonInput.length; counter++){
 var item = jsonInput[counter];
 if(item.object === item.parent) {
  root = item;
  break;
 }
}

var returnValue = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(root));
root.visited = true;
return returnValue;
}

function findChildrens(parentObject) {
var childs = [];
for (var counter = 0; counter < jsonInput.length; counter++){
 var item = jsonInput[counter];
 if(item.parent === parentObject.object && !item.visited) {
  var child = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item));
  item.visited = true;
  child.childs = findChildrens(child);
  childs.push(child);
 }
}
return childs;
}
```

Comment: `{"object":"A", "parent":"A"}` how is this object its own parent? Well, technically you can do that, but is it correct?

Comment: Yeah, root of the object in my case will be represented as `A` is parent of `A`

Answer (score -1):

A simpler solution with a linear runtime.

```js
var data = [
  {"object":"A", "parent":"A"},
  {"object":"B", "parent":"A"},
  {"object":"C", "parent":"A"},
  {"object":"D", "parent":"B"},
  {"object":"E", "parent":"B"},
  {"object":"F", "parent":"D"},
  {"object":"G", "parent":"D"},
  {"object":"H", "parent":"E"},
  {"object":"I", "parent":"E"},
  {"object":"J", "parent":"C"},
  {"object":"K", "parent":"C"},
  {"object":"L", "parent":"J"},
  {"object":"M", "parent":"J"},
  {"object":"N", "parent":"K"},
  {"object":"O", "parent":"K"},
  {"object":"P", "parent":"N"},
  {"object":"Q", "parent":"N"},
  {"object":"R", "parent":"O"},
  {"object":"S", "parent":"O"}
];

var rootNodes = data.filter(function(node) {
  if (node.object in this)
    throw new Error("duplicate object " + node.object);

  this[node.object] = node;
  node.children = [];

  if (node.parent === node.object) return true;
  var parent = this[node.parent];

  if (!parent)
    throw new Error("invalid parent " + node.parent);

  parent.children.push(node);
}, Object.create(null));


console.log(rootNodes);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  max-height: 100%!important
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this would fail if the sequence of objects change. e.g. if you move `{"object":"A", "parent":"A"}` at the end of the array, it will fail